# Getting error when converting timestamp column to time

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-timestamp, dbeaver

I am getting the following error message, when trying to convert timestamp column to time.

```
Error message:

SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

Here is my sql snippets I have been using to convert the column over, but all give me the above error:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.time(timestamp) AS myTime from tableA.time

SELECT "time"(timestamp) AS myTime from tableA.time

SELECT to_char(cast(timestamp as "time")) from tableA.time

select timestamp::time from tableA.time
```

What has worked for me but what I do not need, since I need to run mathematical  operations on the time, is below the sql scripts.

```
SELECT
      EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) AS HOUR,
      EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM timestamp) AS MINUTE,
      EXTRACT(SECOND FROM timestamp) AS SECOND
  FROM tableA.time;
```

is there any way I could check the properties of the column to see if the reason the column is not converting to time? I have tried simple lines like this (`select '2016-10-01 12:12:12'::time`) that work perfectly fine not sure why the whole column is not converting over. If anyone could provide me some help that would be great!

thank you in advance.

-EDIT-

I looked at the column with the timestamp and the type of the column is "timestamp without time zone". Maybe that is what is causing the error.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you fix this issue? If yes, please share the solution too.

Comment: @Pallavi i did not left the company I was working at regarding this.

Comment: you mean, you left the company and did not work on this issue again?

Comment: correct @pallavi I do not have access to those systems

Comment: ok no problem thanks.